# Setting where clause in LINQ query in loop always executes last where clause that was set

Tags: linq, dynamic, foreach, predicate

So I have a bunch of UltraTreeNodes.  I am trying to iterate through them and assign a LINQ query to the Tag property which will be executed at a later point when a user clicks on the node.  The only thing that changes on the query for each node is the variable in the where clause.  However, when the node is clicked and the query is finally executed from the Tag, it always uses the query (and it's where variable) that was assigned last in the foreach loop.

Does it behave that way because all of the Tags are referencing the same query so the same where variable is being assigned to over and over?  Is there a way to avoid this behavior without having to create predicates on the fly and pass those in?

**UPDATE** - Sorry, here is the code:

```
var query = from result in results
                    where result.SchedulingStatus != SchedulerRunStatus.Scheduled 
                    group result by result.UserId into users
                    select new {users.Key, Count = users.Count()};


        foreach (var user in query)
        {
            UltraTreeNode efdUserNode = new UltraTreeNode();
            efdUserNode.Text = user.Key + " (" + user.Count + ")";
            efdUserNode.Key = user.Key;
            IEnumerable<DownloadResultSummary> nodeQuery = from result in efdDetail.DownloadResultSummaries
                              where
                                  result.SchedulingStatus != SchedulerRunStatus.Scheduled &
                                  result.UserId == user.Key
                              select result;

            efdUserNode.Tag = nodeQuery;

            efdUserNode.Override.NodeAppearance.Image = Properties.Resources.user;
            this.efdNode.Nodes.Add(efdUserNode);
        }
```

Comment: Could you post some code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it always uses the query (and it's where variable) that was assigned
>   last in the foreach loop.

You are <strike>most likely</strike> closing over the loop variable - since your query is only executed way later it will take the value of the variable *at that time* - which is the one assigned last.

Make a local copy of the loop variable inside the `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach (var user in query)
{
   User localUser = user;
   //use localUser now instead
   //..
}
```

The part where you are closing over the loop variable is here:

```
   where result.SchedulingStatus != SchedulerRunStatus.Scheduled 
         && result.UserId == user.Key
        select result;
```

replace this with:

```
   where result.SchedulingStatus != SchedulerRunStatus.Scheduled 
         && result.UserId == localUser.Key
        select result;
```

For more details see ["Closing over the loop variable considered harmful"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I should've been more clear, but I'm actually iterating over something else and creating a new UltraTreeNode in each iteration.

Comment: Sweet, thank you!  Sorry for the terrible inefficiency in my ability to post questions on Stackoverflow.